# Use CMake with compiled library and retain include lib/file.hpp structure

Tags: c++, cmake, directory-structure

I have a project with the following structure, where mod1 and 2 are dependencies that live in external repos but are undergoing developement in parallel:

```
projFoo
 - inc
   - component1
     -subcomp11
      - a.hpp
   - component2
       -b.hpp
 - src
   - component1
     -subcomp11
      - a.cpp
   - component2
      -b.cpp
   CMakeLists.txt
 - modules
   - mod1
     - inc
        - f1.hpp
     - src
        - f1.cpp
     - CMakeLists.txt
   - mod2
     - inc
     - src
```

Then the CMakeLists.txt at mod1

```
# projFoo/mod1/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(mod1-lib STATIC src/f1.cpp)
target_include_directories(mod1-lib PUBLIC include)
```

Then the problem I have is that, from projFoo I can no longer do:

```
#include "mod1/f1.hpp"
```

but have to do instead

```
 #include "f1.hpp"
```

Leading to loss of readability and  problems when mod 2 has a file with the same name, for instance.

The following alternatives come to mind:

- Adding an additional redundantly named mod1 directory: "modules/mod1/inc/mod1/f1.h".

  Seems cumbersome and innecesary, lenghtens paths horribly, cannot do nested modules.
- Getting rid of the src and inc separation and mix header and source files.

  Not used to seeing it and haven't done it before. Also seems I would have to include the whole parent directory. Any reason why it's less common? Also would mean a major restructuring of the project.
- Getting CMake to somehow re-arange the files in the build dir, and include headers from there.

  No idea how to do it or if it's possible. Seems like a complicated thing to implement and maintain. Slightly worried it might break source code navigation (currently using VSCode), especially on a failed compilation.

Comment: When you say "I can no longer do", which component contains that include statement? Is it code in mod1, mod2, or your main projFoo? If the code of mod1 contains statements like these, your source tree should reflect that.

Comment: That include statement  is contained in the main projFoo (editing now for clarification). 
Nevertheless I imagine that the way of #include'ing should be the same in .h from mod1 and mod2 since they might evenutally be #inlcude'd from projFoo, (and thus compiled with the same -I flags).

Comment: `I can no longer do:` You could never do that, there is no `mod1` directory that has `f1.hpp`. `Getting CMake to somehow re-arange the files in the build dir, and include headers from there.

No idea how to do it` Create a directory named mod1  and copy the file and add that directory to include search path. I would use option a, it communicates intent clearly, there are include files in this dir, and they are reachable via `mod1/f1.h`.